# Tensorflow outputs an additional 'b' when evaluating a string tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I've recently installed tensorflow into my Conda:
while running following code it gives me an additional 'b'.
I don't know the reason for that 'b'..? 
Why is it being printed and how to get rid of it? This program is running in Tensorflow environment implemented in Jupyter NoteBook

```
import tesnorflow as tf
msg_1 = tf.constant('Welcome to TensorFlow')
with tf.Session() as s:
    print(s.sub(msg_1))
```

results in

```
b'Welcome to TensorFlow'
```

[See also here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKbYD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow represents strings as Bytes objects. [This 'b' is Python's way of marking Bytes objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal). You can convert the Bytes object returned by `session.run()` to a regular python string by applying .decode():

```
print(s.run(msg_1).decode('UTF-8'))
```